# Media center for bananian linux

Tags: linux, video-streaming, media-server

I have an Banana Pi with Bananian 15.04 r01 running on it. At the moment I use it as download and FTP server. With the VLC player it is even possible to stream videos to my pc but I can't jump to a specific time in the video while streaming. To do this, I want to install a media center on my banana pi.

Is there a lightweight media center for bananian that allows me to fast forward and jump to a time in a video? It should have an web interface so I can access it via network on my pc. I don't really care for more features.

I have only found media centers like xbmc which have to be flashed and can't be installed manually on my bananian as far as I know, correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that a `DLNA` server is able to stream video files and can easily run on bananian linux.

Here are the steps to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install minidlna
```

Open `/etc/minidlna.conf`with a text editor and add the directory where the video files are. In my case it has to be `media_dir=V,/disk1`

You just have to restart the `minidlna` service with:

```
sudo service minidlna restart
```

When you open `http://<banana-pi-ip>:8200/` you should see how far `MiniDLNA` is with scanning the media directorys.

Now just have to start an `DLNA` client or the VLC player and open the playlist with `CTRL + L` and click and open `Universal Plug'n'Play` under `Local Network` and you should see your banana pi.